# onpagechanged for flipview (winjs)

Tags: javascript, windows-8, dom-events, winjs

I would like to know if the **flipview control** of the winjs library (win8) has got an **event**, which it called when the **page turns**, no matter if by keyboard or by mouseclick or swiping?

I was Googling for it, but i could just find other methods which does not fire at the right moment.

is there maybe a way you can make such events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [onpagechanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211713.aspx) event. This will fire when the user switches pages no matter the mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the *pagecompleted* event. Used it in one of my apps and it worked. Hope it works for you too :)